# MS Excel - Match 3 columns between two sheets. When matches are found, copy a 4th column from each to a third sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When the all three columns "Last Name, First Name and DOB" match on any rows between the 2 sheets, I need to have the account numbers from the matching rows listed on a third sheet. There are thousands of rows in each sheet. There will likely be multiple matches for some accounts. I prefer to put the functions on the 3rd sheet so that I can change out the lists in the first 2 sheets without needing to update them.

```
Sheet1          
Acct #  Last Name   First Name  DOB
89158   Stevens     John        1/23/2012

Sheet2          
Acct #  Last Name   First Name  DOB
124578  Stevens     John        1/23/2012

Sheet3          
Sheet1 Acct #   Sheet2 Acct#
89158           124578
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have any code for this? people are more willing to fix problem of your solution than to just give you a solution

Comment: =IF(MATCH(Sheet1!B2&C2&D2,Sheet2!B:B&C:C&D:D, 0),Sheet1!A2,"")

I am able to get the account number from sheet1 onto sheet3 using what I have so far.

Comment: Could there be more than 1 possible outcome on each sheet? Like another John Smith with DOB 1/23/2012 but another account number?

Comment: It is possible, yes.

Comment: Cool, answer posted for now, i will come back to it tomorrow if it is still outstanding.

Comment: Glitch_Doctor - The answer below is close, it needs a little bit of tweaking and I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting list A and List B into a sheet and then using this formula: =ISNA(MATCH(B2&C2&D2,I:I&J:J&K:K,0)) Then I created another sheet where I added list B and then list A and used the same formula. Once the calculation was complete for each sheet, I used filters to only list the matches for the first lists in each spreadsheet.

I then took the matches for each sheet and listed them side by side in the third sheet. I made sure the sort was matched between the two lists and then was able to scroll through a page at a time and identify a few users with multiple account numbers in each system.

It's not as automated as I would like, but it is done for now. Thank you Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

**This works with duplicate values**

The formula will need to be entered as an array (once copy and pasted while still in the formula bar hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and the range adjusted to fit your total values.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$50,MATCH(1,($C2=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$50)*($D2=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$50)*($E2=Sheet1!$D$2:$D$50),0),1),"No match found")
```

The exact same formula can be used again changing `Sheet1!` to `Sheet2!`.

This will search for the last name that is in `Sheet3!C2`, first name that is in `Sheet3!D2` and the DOB that is in `Sheet3!E2`.

I have only locked off the column in case you are looking to use this for a large volume of data and wish to drag it down.

If you want to display the additional account numbers that meet the search criteria and are only using sheet 3 to search for *one* person, then you will need to look at using `INDEX()`, `MATCH()` and `SMALL()`.

I had looked to include this alternative in my answer too but I am now leaving the office. It won't take me long to conjure if you struggle so drop me a comment and I will be happy to explain how it all works.

**EDIT: To list all ID's found for the search criteria - Leave blanks where not found**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$50,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C$2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$50)*COUNTIF($D$2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$50)*COUNTIF($E$2,Sheet1!$D$2:$D$50),ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$50)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$50))+1),ROW(Sheet1!1:1)),1),"")
```

Again, replace sheet 1 for sheet 2 and update the ranges to match what you are searching through, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the formula bar to make the formula an array then you can drag it down to cover all the potential matches, best to aim for what you believe would be the highest number of duplicate IDs.

Let me know how you get on, if this answers your question, please mark this as an answer using the tick to the left, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This doesn't appear to be quite what I am looking for. I need to find matches of Last Name, First Name and DOB between Sheet1 and any row of Sheet2 and then placing the account numbers from both sheets on the empty Sheet3. I hope this helps put this in context.

Comment: Make sure that the range size is the same length. What you have explained is what this formula achieves though it will find the first match only. I will take a look at this later on my lunch break and update it with the answer that finds the duplicated values also. Just for good measure, is sheet 3 a list of data or just a search field you will use to find 1 person at a time?

Comment: This was missing Sheet references, this will work now for 1 match, i will take a look at multiple matches now

Comment: @KrisHansen Answer updated, both formulas now correct, please see edit section for formula that will return all matches to search criteria.

Comment: Contextual clarification - Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 have data exported from 2 different systems. Each system has it's own account number. I am trying to match up the accounts between the two systems by matching last name, first name and DOB. When any account from sheet 1 has a match in sheet 2, I want to list both account numbers in Sheet 3. This will be used to update one of the systems so the account numbers match in both systems. Ideally the formula would only be entered into Sheet 3 so that sheet 1 and 2 could be updates with new lists as needed.

Thanks again for your help.